# Will autotools recompile the entire project if I change the prefix with configure?

Tags: build, autotools, configure

I just configured, built, and installed gcc specifying a wrong prefix. Will I be rebuilding all binaries after configuring with a different `--prefix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it compiles everything from scratch.